# Unable to watch/observe scope?

Tags: angularjs

`<button-large color="green" click="createWorkstation()" busy="disableSave()" busyLabel="Saving...">Save</button-large>`

I'm not able to watch changes to the output of `disableSave()`.  The console.log()'s shown in my directive are never triggered when the output of .busy is changed.  What am I doing wrong?

```
directive('buttonLarge', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            busy: '&',
            click: '&'
        },
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        template: '<button class="buttonL" ng-transclude/>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            //when the button is busy, disable the button
            if (angular.isDefined(scope.busy())) {
                scope.$watch(scope.busy(), function () {
                    console.log('watched');
                });
                attrs.$observe(scope.busy(), function () {
                    console.log('observed');
                });
            }

            //setup click event - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/-uVE5WJWwLA
            if (angular.isDefined(scope.click)) {
                element.bind('click', scope.click);
            }
        }
    }
})
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.newWorkstationDialog = function (workflowProcess) {
    var d = $dialog.
        dialog({
            resolve: {
                workflowProcess: function () {
                    return workflowProcess;
                }
            }
        }).
        open('/partials/admin/'+workflowProcess.entity.slug+'/setup.htm', ['$scope', 'dialog', ..., function ($scope, dialog, ...) {
            $scope.saving = false;

            /* Create the workstation */
            $scope.createWorkstation = function () {
                console.log('saving');
                $scope.saving = true;
                $timeout(function () {
                    $scope.saving = false;
                    console.log('stopped saving');
                }, 1000);
            }

            //Should the save button be disabled?
            $scope.disableSave = function () {
                return $scope.saving;//|| $scope.form.$valid;
            }

            $scope.cancel = function () {
                dialog.close();
            }
        }]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax of watching in not correct .You should be not using scope when doing watch because internally it  use $parse service which internally attach scope . So you need to modify your code as below

```
 1st option 

 scope.$watch(function(){
return scope.busy()
}, function (newvalue,oldvalue) {
                    console.log('watched');
                });

2nd option

scope.$watch('busy()', function (newvalue,oldvalue) {
                    console.log('watched');
                });
```

Comment: kindly share the fiddle or plunker demo pls

Comment: For the life of me, I've never been able to get Angular stuff to work on JSFiddle... here's my attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/Webnet/HkXNc/

Comment: got it you are missing a call to scope.$apply() in click function thats why it is not working .Kindly see the plunker which is logging properly in the console http://plnkr.co/edit/f2yQqCow7svx3njoVkmM?p=preview

Comment: Btw plnkr.co works much better for angular. They have a template for it and you're ready to go.